# Как будет работать программа?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем так пишут и как будет работать программа?

```
public class Human {
  public void voice(){
    System.out.println("Я человек");
  }
}

public class Worker extends Human{

  public void voice(){
     super.voice();
     System.out.println("Я рабочий");
   }
 }

 public class MyClass{

   public static void main(String[] args){
     Worker worker =new Human();
     worker.voice();
     }
   }
```

Вопрос в том,что будет и зачем в дочернем классе писать super,если же метод был переопределен? Почему просто,не использовать родительский метод по умолчанию?

Comment: Программа работать не будет, потому что не скомпилируется. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А затем, что, чтобы добавить вывод строки "я рабочий", нужно переопределить родительский метод. А super нужно писать, чтобы получить доступ к родительским неprivate конструкторам, методам, переменным, константам. Вот и здесь нам необходимо выполнить то, что находится в методе родителя, потому мы и вызываем метод родителя, чтобы не плодить одинаковый код.
Хотя, если такого метода нет в нашем подклассе, super можно и не писать (но желательно, чтобы указать на то, что метод, переменная или константа родительская)(к конструктору это не относится)

Comment: Так получается, что когда вызывается метод. Мы лезем в родителя, смотрим  что этот метод переопределен, лезем в дочерний класс, а там, снова вызов родителя. Вот это мне не понятно.
То ест он будет выводить 
`Я человек Я рабочий`  или как-то иначе? Мне вот это и не понятно.

Comment: Нет мы лезем сначала в дочерний класс, затем по ходу его выполнения лезем в родительский. Он действительно выведет это.

Answer (score 1):

Программа не скомпилируется

> public class My **class**{

Лишний раз написано **class**

> Worker worker =new Human();

Так тоже не правильно, нельзя вызвать конструктор родительского класса, наоборот можно.

> system.out.print ("Я человек");

**system** написано с маленькой буквы, а должно быть **System**

Comment: Это все опечатки. Писал с телефона